# Argument of type 'Http' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Http'

Tags: angular

I have following error:

> [ts] Argument of type 'Http' is not assignable to parameter of type
>   'Http'.   Property '_backend' is protected but type 'Http' is not a
>   class derived from 'Http'. (parameter) http: Http

This error is in file auth.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

import { AuthHttp, AuthConfig } from 'angular2-jwt'

import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthGuard } from './auth.guard';
import { RoleGuard } from './role.guard';
import { GuestGuard } from './guest.guard';

export function authHttpServiceFactory( http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
  return new AuthHttp(new AuthConfig(), http, options);
}

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    AuthGuard,
    RoleGuard,
    GuestGuard,
    {
      provide: AuthHttp,
      useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
      deps: [Http, RequestOptions]
    }
  ]
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

What is wrong?

Comment: What versions of angular and angular2-jwt are you using?

Comment: "angular2-jwt": "^0.2.0" package.json https://pastebin.com/gYiqMV5m

Comment: I can't see any obvious errors in your code, but I can't see the versions of your angular modules in the package.json you posted. Is your angular modules from before version `2.4.2`?

Comment: How can I check version?

Comment: Try running this in the root directory of your application: `cat node_modules/@angular/*/package.json|grep -E "((^ {2}\"name\")|(^ {2}\"version\"))"` to get the version per angular module and paste the result

Answer (score 0):

Check if you don't have any library referenced with `npm link`. There is [issue with linked dependencies](https://github.com/iXHensel/npm-link-angular-test-base).

Would love to help more but I'm currently struggling with the same issue in different setup.